# Twisted big files transfer

Tags: twisted, file-transfer

I write client-server application like this:
client(c#) <-> server (twisted; ftp proxy and additional functional) <-> ftp server

Server has two classes: my own class-protocol inherited from LineReceiever protocol and FTPClient from twisted.protocols.ftp.

But when client sends or gets big files (10 Gb - 20 Gb) server catches MemoryError. I don't use any buffers in my code. It happens when after call transport.write(data) data appends to inner buffer of reactor's writers (correct me if I wrong).

What should I use to avoid this problem? Or should I change approach to the problem?

I found out that for big streams, I should use IConsumer and IProducer interfaces. But finally it will invoke transfer.write method and effect will be the same. Or am I wrong?

**UPD:**

Here is logic of file download/upload (from ftp through Twisted server to client on Windows):

Client sends some headers to Twisted server and after that begins send of file. Twisted server receive headers and after that (if it needs) invoke `setRawMode()`, open ftp connection and recieves/sends bytes from/to client and after all close connections. Here is a part of code that uploads files:

FTPManager class

```
def _ftpCWDSuccees(self, protocol, fileName):
        self._ftpClientAsync.retrieveFile(fileName, FileReceiver(protocol))



class FileReceiver(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, proto):
        self.__proto = proto

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.__proto.transport.write(data)

    def connectionLost(self, why = connectionDone):
        self.__proto.connectionLost(why)
```

main proxy-server class:

```
class SSDMProtocol(LineReceiver)
...
```

After SSDMProtocol object (call `obSSDMProtocol`) parse headers it invoke method that open ftp connection (`FTPClient` from  `twisted.protocols.ftp`) and set object of FTPManager field _ftpClientAsync and call `_ftpCWDSuccees(self, protocol, fileName)` with `protocol = obSSDMProtocol` and when file's bytes recieved invokes `dataReceived(self, data)` of FileReceiver object.

And when `self.__proto.transport.write(data)` invoked, data appends to inner buffer faster than sending back to client, therefore memory runs out. May be I can stop reading when the buffer reaches a certain size and resume reading after buffer will be all send  to client? or something like that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're passing a 20 gigabyte (gigabit?) string to `transport.write`, you're going to need at least 20 gigabytes (gigabits?) of memory - probably more like 40 or 60 due to the extra copying necessary when dealing with strings in Python.

Even if you never pass a single string to `transport.write` that is 20 gigabytes (gigabits?), if you repeatedly call `transport.write` with short strings at a rate faster than your network can handle, the send buffer will eventually grow too large to fit in memory and you'll encounter a `MemoryError`.

The solution to both of these problems is the producer/consumer system.  The advantage that using `IProducer` and `IConsumer` gives you is that you'll never have a 20 gigabyte (gigabit?) string and you'll never fill up a send buffer with too many shorter strings.  The network will be throttled so that bytes are not read faster than your application can deal with them and forget about them.  Your strings will end up on the order of 16kB - 64kB, which should easily fit in memory.

You just need to adjust your use of `FileReceiver` to include registration of the incoming connection as a producer for the outgoing connection:

```
class FileReceiver(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, outgoing):
        self._outgoing = outgoing

    def connectionMade(self):
        self._outgoing.transport.registerProducer(self.transport, streaming=True)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self._outgoing.transport.write(data)
```

Now whenever `self._outgoing.transport`'s send buffer fills up, it will tell `self.transport` to pause.  Once the send buffer empties out, it will tell `self.transport` to resume.  `self.transport` nows how to undertake these actions at the TCP level so that data coming into your server will also be slowed down.

Comment: Thank you for answer, Jean-Paul! I don't send 20 gigabyte string immediately to `transport.write`, data writes to socket when it comes from ftp socket (or vice versa). And it is not a string. it's bytes of file from ftp server or from client. I use string only for some commands. Can I use Twisted to upload (download) a big file from client to ftp through Twisted proxy server? and what should I do for this if it is possible with Twisted?

Comment: Sorry, your question is too vague to answer in any more detail.  Please consider adding more details about what you're doing - see <http://sscce.org/> for some further advice.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH!!! I think it would be cool if you could add this information (or any example) to the documentation for the IConsumer/IProducer interfaces. Because personally, I did not realize that I can use these interfaces in this way (that I just register producer and just call the SAME METHOD and everything works). But it's only IMHO...Thanks!